# rtsp to youtube streaming not working in windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

ffmpeg run in windows, i use this code for streaming RTSP to youtube streaming :

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 12:00:00 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:martin123@103.76.204.2:554/Streaming/Channels/101 -tune zerolatency -g 2 -c:v copy -t 12:00:00 -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/zgzx-7sff-32xz-bbup-a25c
```

but i got this error :

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ffmpeg\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 12:00:00 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:martin123@103.76.204.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/101 -tune zerolatency -g 2 -c:v copy -t 12:00:00 -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/zgzx-7sff-32xz-bbup-a25c
ffmpeg version git-2020-07-20-43a08d9 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
  libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
  libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[lavfi @ 000001a7dc40e380] No such filter: 'rtsp://admin:martinxxx'
rtsp://admin:martin123@103.76.204.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/101: Invalid argument
```

can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this code :

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 12:00:00 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:martin123@103.76.204.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/101 -tune zerolatency -g 2 -c:v copy -t 12:00:00 -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/zgzx-7sff-32xz-bbup-a25c
```

working now